# Insert value for session user if function returns true?

Tags: php

I want to replace the null in my database with a 1 if my function returns true. I am not sure how to do it when it's for the session user.

In PHP should I use a 0 or a 1 for true?

This is the first part of my code that includes the session user and the return of the javascript function.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
mysql_select_db('db');
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
if(!$username){
    die("Please login");
}
else
{
    $query="select *from users WHERE username='$username' ";
    $run=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
        $admin=$row['username'];
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>practice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Substyle.css">  
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/general.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```